# NGINX Ingress dealing hostAliases fail due to SSL error

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I've configured a NGINX Ingress to use SSL. This works fine, but I'm trying to use hostAliases to route all requests from one domain back to my cluster and its failing with the following error:

> Error: unable to verify the first certificate

My alias:

```
hostAliases:
    - ip: "MY.CLUSTER.IP"
      hostnames:
      - "my.domain.com"
```

Is there a way to use this aliasing and still get ssl working?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/add-entries-to-pod-etc-hosts-with-host-aliases/) host alias is just a record in /etc/hosts file, which overwrites "usual" DNS resolution. If I understand your issue correctly, in this case you just need to have valid TLS certificate for "my.domain.com" installed on MY.CLUSTER.IP

Hope it helps.